# Linear Regression python

Tags: python, linear-regression

I want to implement the Linear Regression in python, without scikit-learn, but I dont know why, the variable "error" always increment and that shouldnt, and I think maybe the problem is in the Formula, but I dont no where.

Is the algorthm fine?

```
def linear_regression(X, y, learning_rate=0.01, max_num_iterations=500, opt=True):
    # Your code goes here
    # Your code goes here
    w = np.zeros(len(X[0]))
    error=0
    gradient=X
    variable =X
    print(f"X:{X}")

    for a in range(max_num_iterations):

                o = np.sum(X*w)
                error = y-o
                print(f"sum1:{np.sum(X*w)}")
                print(f"y:{y}")
                print(f"error: {error}")
                print (f"gradient1: {gradient}")
                print(f"w: {w}")
                for i in range(800):

                    gradient[i][0]=-X[i][0]*error[i]

                    gradient[i][1]=-X[i][1]*error[i]

                gradient=-learning_rate*gradient

                w=w+gradient


    return w
```

Comment: `error = y-o` with incrementing `error` means than `y > o` ; is that what you've expected? Maybe [`abs(val)`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#abs) will do?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code merely defines a function and quits without executing.

Comment: @FilipMalczak I mean that the error is bigger everytime, and I think, that always should be lower. that's how I think the algorithm should work

Comment: Then figure out why `y>o` or check whether the formula should be `y-o` and not `o-y`. Or maybe elements in `X` and `w` align with signs in this particular way? Dude, it's your exercise, I'm throwing hints here.